Transparent status bar color Android and React Native hybrid app
Background
I have an app that is composed of Android and react native.
Issue
When I set the status bar colour to translucent, the toolbar on the native screens overlap the status bar. Setting translucent makes the height of the screen to increase and goes full screen.
In react native:
  useEffect(() => {
    StatusBar.setTranslucent(true);
    StatusBar.setBackgroundColor('transparent');
  }, []);

Alternatively, setting translucent in Android achieves the same thing.
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
window.statusBarColor = getColor(android.R.color.transparent)


Is it possible to set transparent status bar colour in react native without going full screen?
